# Solve $\sin^6(x+\pi/6)+\cos^6(x+\pi/6)=\frac{7}{6}\cos4x+\sin4x$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sin^6(x+\frac{\pi}{6})+\cos^6(x+\frac{\pi}{6})=\frac{7}{6}\cos4x+\sin4x$$

I have tried to reduce the equality into: $$(\sin^2(x+\frac{\pi}{6})+\cos^2(x+\frac{\pi}{6}))(\sin^4(x+\frac{\pi}{6})+\cos^4(x+\frac{\pi}{6})-\sin^2(x+\frac{\pi}{6})\cos^2(x+\frac{\pi}{6}))=\frac{1}{6}(\cos^2{2x}-\sin^2{2x})+\cos4x+\sin4x$$ but it doesn't work.

Comment: You're not new anymore, so please add some context to your question.

Comment: Sorry sir, but what do you mean "context"? (I'm so sorry because my English is not good)

Comment: Tiago, add your attempts, what you have already tried... and there is no question.... Where does this task come from? What do you have difficulties with? What have you learned so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll get you started. Let $y:=x+\frac{\pi}{6}$ so, since $\sin^2y+\cos^2y=1$,$$\begin{align}\sin^6y+\cos^6y&=\sin^4y-\sin^2y\cos^2y+\cos^4y\\&=1-3\sin^2y\cos^2y\\&=1-\frac34\sin^22y\\&=1-\frac34(\sin(2x+\tfrac{\pi}{3}))^2\\&=1-\frac{3}{16}(\sin2x+\sqrt{3}\cos2x)^2.\end{align}$$Now you just need to keep using double-angle formulae.